# C# Transaction Scope with 2 databases on same server causing exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I have a scenario where I must insert data to 2 databases, but on the same database server and it must be inside a transaction. I am using entity framework 6 and I am wrapping each of my db saves inside a transaction scope. The issue is the first database save works fine but when I attempt the 2nd save to the other database an error occurs as follows.

**Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.**

I have read some articles that I must enable a feature within SQL server but I dont believe our DBA's will allow this modification. So I would like to verify first that there is no other solution in lieu of enabling DTC.

Here is my existing C# code, some specifics removed for brevity.

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    //database 1
    using (var context1 = new SomeContext())
    {
        //......
        //.....
        context1.SaveChanges();
    }

    //database 2
    using (var context2 = new SomeContext2())
    {
        //...
        context2.SaveChanges();
    }

    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, just don't do it in the same transaction

Comment: It has to be in the same transaction, if it fails to insert in database 2 after it saves to database 1 then there is a problem.

Comment: Why does it have to be the same transaction, why would it fail if its not in the same transaction? I'm assuming DB2 is for some reason dependent on DB1.  As you said before you're DBA does not want to make the required changes to support Escalation.  So commit or ignore the first transaction and just commit directly and rollback if needed

Comment: What you are trying to do is distributed transaction, and it should be quite clear from that that you cannot (reliably) perform it without DTC. There should be third party between 2 databases to coordinate commit/rollback between them.

Comment: Ok, thx for clarification so I basically have to enable DTS or I have to manually handle transactions in my code and explicitly remove a previous commit from the 1st database save.

Comment: Note that manually removing commit is not reliable (imagine process crash after exception on second database call but before you were able to remove commit in first.).

Comment: So without a 3rd party coordinator or use of MS DTC enabled I have no choice but a manual process. Is their any reason a MS SQL DBA would not want this enabled?

Comment: MS DTC _is_ third party coodinator. And yes - you will have to convince your DBA to do that, they won't enable it easily. Maybe they will provide alternative solution for your specific case.

Comment: Btw, I read a bit more that MSDTC is for cross server transactions and not cross databases on the same server. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than you writing a stored procedure to accomplish the work for you, there's no other way you're going to be able to get your code to do this without MSDTC.  MSDTC does the job of brokering transactions across disparate sources (i.e. two databases).

Your DBAs may not allow *you* to make the change, because it's a server-level change, but they may turn on the feature themselves.  Just note that if it's a development server, you'll eventually have to do the same to any other servers your project has to run on.

[On MSDTC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/florinlazar/2004/03/04/what-is-msdtc-and-why-do-i-need-to-care-about-it/):

> MSDTC is an acronym for Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator. As the name says, MSDTC is a Windows service providing transaction infrastructure for distributed systems. In this case, a transaction means a general way of structuring the interactions between autonomous agents in a distributed system. Each transaction is a state transformation with four key properties – the ACID properties: Atomic (all or nothing), Consistent (legal), Isolated (independent of concurrent transactions) and Durable (once it happens, it cannot be abrogated). There are different techniques that implement the ACID properties but the most known one is two-phase commit.